# How to allow a user to filter tuples in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I currently have a dictionary which is structured like this:

```
{
    (foo, bar, baz): 1,
    (baz, bat, foobar): 5
}
```

Within this structure, the key is a tuple representing the entry's properties. Outside of the dictionary, I have another tuple:

```
(property1, property2, property3)
```

This maps directly to the keys of the dictionary. I would like the user to be able to input filters to get relevant keys within the dictionary, based on the property. Ideally, this would take the form of a dictionary as well. For example, if the user entered `{property1: foo}`, the program would return:

```
{
    (foo, bar, baz): 1
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on? Have you tried to solve this yourself yet? If so, could you show the code you tried (and describe what it's doing incorrectly)?

Comment: @RobertValencia In my use case, it's possible for the same value to appear in different places in the tuple. For example, the keys `(foo, bar, foo)` and `(bat, bat, bat)` are both valid

Comment: Okay I see. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly possible, but my implementation was not nearly as clean as I hoped it would be. The basic approach is to construct an intermediate dictionary `matcher` which contains the tuple indices to be matched as keys and their corresponding strings (or what have you) as values.

```
def get_property_index(prop):
    try:
        if prop.startswith('property'):
            # given 'property6' returns the integer 5 (0-based index)
            return int(prop[8:]) - 1
        else:
            raise ValueError

    except ValueError:
        raise AttributeError('property must be of the format "property(n)"')

def filter_data(data, filter_map):
    matcher = {}
    for prop, val in filter_map.items():
        index = get_property_index(prop)
        matcher[index] = val

    filtered = {}
    for key, val in data.items():
        # checks to see if *any* of the provided properties match
        # if you want to check if *all* of the provided properties match, use "all"
        if any(key[index] == matcher[index] for index in matcher):
            filtered[key] = val

    return filtered
```

Some example usage is given below, it should match up with the requested usage.

```
data = {
    ('foo', 'bar', 'baz'): 1,
    ('foo', 'bat', 'baz'): 2,
    ('baz', 'bat', 'foobar'): 3
}

filter_map1 = {
    'property1': 'foo'
}

print filter_data(data, filter_map1)
# {('foo', 'bar', 'baz'): 1, ('foo', 'bat', 'baz'): 2}

filter_map2 = {
    'property2': 'bat'  
}

print filter_data(data, filter_map2)
# {('foo', 'bat', 'baz'): 2, ('baz', 'bat', 'foobar'): 3}

filter_map3 = {
    'property2': 'bar',
    'property3': 'foobar'
}

print filter_data(data, filter_map3)
# {('foo', 'bar', 'baz'): 1, ('baz', 'bat', 'foobar'): 3}
```